# How to force Java 7 to create "directory symlinks" on Windows instead of "file symlinks"?

Tags: java, windows, symlink, java-7

I'm using Oracle Java 7 on Windows 64 bit.

When I create a symlink using [Files.createSymbolicLink](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), I notice this behavior:

1. If the target is a directory, a "directory symlink" is created.
2. If the target is a file, a "file symlink" is created.
3. If the target does not exist, a "file symlink" is created.

[The type of the symlink is fixed and never changes](http://www.quora.com/File-Systems/What-are-essential-differences-in-the-implementation-of-Symbolic-Links-between-Windows-and-Linux), regardless of any changes to its target.

Using Windows' native `mklink` command, it is possible to force the link type to be a "directory symlink". Is it possible to achieve this using the native Java API or some library?

One trivial and ugly way is:

1. If the target is a directory, just create the link
2. If the target doesn't exist, create a new empty target directory, create the link, and delete the directory.
3. If the target is a file ... handle it (move it, apply #2, move it back).

Fugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't see a way within the Java APIs to do it.

I checked the Windows JRE code and it looks like the decision is based on the file attributes themselves:

```
try
{
   WindowsFileAttributes windowsfileattributes = WindowsFileAttributes.get(windowspath2, false);
   if(windowsfileattributes.isDirectory() || windowsfileattributes.isDirectoryLink())
      i |= 1;
}
```

The attributes themselves originate from **native** code, and it looks like there is no way to affect them.

Clearly you have other options like manually invoking `mklink` or even manipulating the returned objects using something like `PowerMock` (which is clearly not meant for this purpose).

Another dirty option is to create proxys of all the relevant classes: `Path`, `FileSystem` and `FileSystemProvider`.
The way that it works is that the `Path` returns a `FileSystem` which returns a `FileSystemProvider` - what you need to do is modify how the `FileSystemProvider.createSymbolicLink` methods behaves.

The `createSymbolicLink` method receives a varargs argument which is currently not used - you can pass an argument to it that will indicate your wrapper that it needs to override the way symbolic links are created  - and there you go :)

After writing all of this - the only question I have is - why do you need this kind of behavior?

Comment: Actually there's no great need, I just discovered this behavior via a bug in my program that caused the symlink's target not to be created.